# manage logstash from Java

Tags: java, logstash

I want to manage starting and stopping of logstash from Java. Is there any easy/nice way to do this?

so, can anyone give me an example of how to start logstash  without needing to my logstash instance started from run.bat manually.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the batch file as a process in Java like this

```
String cmd = "cmd /c start C:\\path\\to\\run.bat";
Process logstashProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

And then kill the process calling destroy() method when needed

```
logstashProcess.destroy();
```

You can add these as startup and shutdown hooks of your application (the application whose log you will be analyzing using logstash) or you could just write a standalone Java app which will maintain starting and stopping logstash.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you. This way it might be easier for others to find the correct solution when they face the same problem in future.